# Wpf datagrid show limited row count and scroll after that count

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

i am working on a small stock management application, in which the list of available items and list of items sold are displayed in a datagrid in

WPF MVVM

the problem i am facing is i only want 5 items count to be displayed in the datagrid and the other items should be scrollable with fixed header. Is there any way to achieve it with (ONLY XAML CODE).couldn't find solutions in other forums/post so created a new.
here is my code

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 0 0 0" Text="Available List"/>
            <DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="availablegrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailListCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                      Height="auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ItemCode" Binding="{Binding ItemCode}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding Weight,StringFormat=' {0} gm'}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Comment,FallbackValue=Empty}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sold">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Name="Sold"  Click="Sold_OnClick" Background="Red" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Sold"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Name="Edit1" Click="Edit1_OnClick"  Background="Red" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Edit"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

i tried the ScrollViewer property but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am getting it correct. But I think you should just limit the maximum height of your `DataGrid` in a way that only 5 items fit into the `DataGrid` and the rest could be scrolled to view.

Comment: I have tried limiting the height to 2 for test, it's un scrollable after that

Comment: So wasn't this the behaviour you want? That only show 5 items and you can scroll the rest?

Answer (score 0):

This is a XAML only solution :

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
              ColumnHeaderHeight="30"
              RowHeight="20" 
              Height="130"/>
```

Of course, this code assume that each row are of the same size and that the content will fit inside 20 units, a better approach would be to not set `RowHeight` value, get any `GridDataRow` from code behind, check its `ActualHeight` and affect a custom property that your `DataGrid` `Height` value could bind to using a converter (or hard coding the calculation if you know it will always be 5 times a `GridDataRow.ActualHeight`). This would need code in C#, which you don't want to deal with.